# How to Use z.discriminatedUnion() in TRPC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discriminated-union, zod, trpc.io

Just getting used to trpc. Say I have a standard procedure:

```
update: t.procedure
    .input(z.object({
      id: z.string(),
      type: z.string(),
      content: z.object({ title: z.string() }).nullish()
    }).nullish())
```

Now what I am interested in is the `content` attribute. In my mysql schema, that `content` field is a JSON field. Depending on the `type` field, it will contain different values.

For example. If `type` is `blogPost`, it will contain attributes like `title` & `category`, but if the `type` is set to `landingPage` those attributes will change. (just an example to make it more straightforward, my use case isn't about blogPosts etc.)

As far as I understand, I can solve this with `discriminatedUnion`:

```
z.discriminatedUnion("type", [
    z.object({ type: z.literal("a"), a: z.string() }),
    z.object({ type: z.literal("b"), b: z.string() }),
  ])
  .parse({ type: "a", a: "abc" });
```

but i am not sure how to apply this to my case? I want it to only apply to the content field and keep the other attributes the same.

Comment: The `z.object` schema takes arbitrary schemas for each of it's keys. You could put the `discriminatedUnion` as the value for `content` in the same way that you put `z.string()` as the value for `id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I don't really understand the syntax here with `"type"` - what exactly does this refer to? How would I turn my content object into a discriminated union? Sorry, I feel stuck.

Comment: No worries, I agree the api is a little confusing. When you use `discriminatedUnion` you tell `zod` about a list of types that the union has in it. In order for `TypeScript` to tell which variant is which, one of the fields must be shared between each of the types with a unique value in each case. The `"type"` string is the name of that field. In the example you showed you named that field `type` so you pass in the string `"type"` to tell zod about that. Notice you have a unique literal value stored under `type` in each branch.